# PHP: Add array values togather

Tags: php, arrays, json

This I believe is a little harder than the title makes it sound, but I could be completely wrong. I have an array like this:

```
[["londrina",15],["cascavel",34],["londrina",23],['tiradentes',34],['tiradentes',21]]
```

I want to be able to take the common values, in this case londrina and tiradentes, and add the numbers together. My PHP code is the following:

```
$qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bap WHERE semana = '".$week."'");
    $rows = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry)) {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }

    $resultstr = array();

    foreach($rows as $row) {
        $resultstr[] = '["'.$row['zona'].'",'.$row['numero'].']';

    }
    $result = implode(', ',$resultstr);
    print '['.$result.']';
```

I'm not sure if any more info is needed. The array is being outputted in this format to use for a jquery json graphing plugin. Let me know if anymore info is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT zona,
       SUM(numero) AS sum  
  FROM bap 
 WHERE semana = $week 
 GROUP BY zona
```

Comment: Saying Undefined index: numero

Comment: Is your column called numero? From the look of your code, it is; but if not then replace with the appropriate column that you want summing up

Comment: Yes, that is the collumns name

Comment: Then use `sum` in your PHP code instead, because that SQL aliases the sum of all related values of `numero` in a new temporary column called `sum`.... or change the alias to `numero`

Comment: Thanks! I figured out what was going wrong. Naming the column sum was screwing with the code, I just changed it to numero and everything worked. I didn't even know about the GROUP BY thing.

Comment: There are real benefits to learning SQL, especially as this will be a lot more efficient than doing it in PHP

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$arr = [["londrina",15],["cascavel",34],["londrina",23],['tiradentes',34],['tiradentes',21]];
$new_arr = [];

foreach ($arr as $a) {

    list($name, $num) = $a;

    if (!isset($new_arr[$name])) {
        $new_arr[$name] = 0;
    }

    $new_arr[$name] += $num;
}

var_dump($new_arr);
```

**EDIT FOR OP**

Use this code in its entirety, should give desired result:

```
$qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bap WHERE semana = '".$week."'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry)) {

    $rows[] = array($row['zona'], $row['numero']);
}

$new_arr = [];

foreach ($rows as $a) {

    list($name, $num) = $a;

    if (!isset($new_arr[$name])) {
        $new_arr[$name] = 0;
    }

    $new_arr[$name] += $num;
}

var_dump($new_arr);
```

Comment: Haha, I guess I am, 2 minutes, never answered one so fast

Comment: This isn't working... The PHP code that I wrote outputs that array and trying to incorporate your code into mine is giving me the error Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()